# Keras L2 normalisation of concatenated vectors

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to construct a network in Keras that should output two unit length vectors of dimensions 3 and 4 respectively and am currently using a final Dense layer of dimension 7 to achieve this. My problem now is that I have now idea how to add a layer after this that normalises the lengths of the two vectors separately. From what I understand one can usually normalise a vector output with something like

```
l2_norm = Lambda(lambda  x: K.l2_normalize(x,axis=1))(prevDense)
```

but it is not clear how to change this two treat the two "halves" separately. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to use a [Lambda](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda) layer to slice the tensors first and then do the normalization. In this case you may do the following:

```py
# slicing the tensors
slice1 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:4])(prevDense)
slice2 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:3])(prevDense)

l2_norm_slice1 = Lambda(lambda  x: K.l2_normalize(slice1,axis=1))(slice1)
l2_norm_slice2 = Lambda(lambda  x: K.l2_normalize(slice2,axis=1))(slice2)
```

Hope this helps!